# Best Practive for widget overlaying a MaterialApp / Using nested Material Apps

Tags: flutter

What's the best way to make a widget overlay a MaterialApp? I can't just wrap a Scaffold because this way, the widget would disappear when navigating away. So whats the best way to achieve this?

Like the YouTube Miniplayer:

[image]

Edit: I found a way, I achieve it bby using two nested MaterialApps like this

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        MaterialApp(
          home: HomePage(),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 16,
          right: 16,
          bottom: 16,
          child: Container(
            height: 30,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Is that a good way to achieve this?